# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dota'

Tags: python, django, import

I get the following error when running my Django project:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_email.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dota.settings import SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN, SENDGRID_API_KEY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dota'
```

Ok i created an `.env` file in the root of my folder. I exported everything and made a setup in settings.py file in dota directory that is main directory where settings.py file is.

`settings.py`:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_TLS')
DOMAIN = os.getenv("DOMAIN")
```

After that I tried to import this including secret key that i stored in as env variable.
Here is the code.

`send_mail.py`:

```
import jwt
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from dota.settings import SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN, SENDGRID_API_KEY


def send_confirmation_email(email, username):
    token = jwt.encode({'user': username}, SECRET_KEY,
                       algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
    context = {
        'small_text_detail': 'Thank you for '
                             'creating an account. '
                             'Please verify your email '
                             'address to set up your account.',
        'email': email,
        'domain': DOMAIN,
        'token': token,
    }
    # locates our email.html in the templates folder
    msg_html = render_to_string('email.html', context)
    message = Mail(
        # the email that sends the confirmation email
        from_email=Email('example@gmail.com'),
        to_email=Email('veljko33614@its.edu.rs'),  # list of email receivers
        subject='Account activation',  # subject of your email
        content=msg_html
    )
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(apikey=SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        sg.send(message)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

my send_mail.py is in the **users** app

After I run send_mail.py I get that error shown above.

I will give you a tree of my folders so you can see why I cant solve this. I really dont have a clue.

**my tree folder**
https://prnt.sc/rathyu

Comment: How do you run your project?

Comment: It's generally better to use code block formatting for backtraces: that makes them clearer, as it preserves newlines.

Comment: I run my project with a graphql mutations and queries. After I register email must be sent to email with that user povides. I hardcoded email here just to test it but i get that error when i just run send_mail.py

Comment: code block formating. What you mean buy that?

Comment: No, how do you *start* running the project? You must issue some command for it to start.

Comment: Its a big app using React + Django. I run server and after I use createUser mutation it put  that user in PosgreSQL DB. I run only python.send_mail.py . thats how i run this single file

Comment: It says module not found but dota folder exist as settings.py file. From settings.py I just want to import SENDGRID_API_KEY and all the rest that i already showed you on my post. I also have .env file were i store env variables. settings.py is for getting those .env variables only. And then i want to import those files in users folder but its says module not found.

Comment: Maybe i dont load .env file corectly ? i really dont know

Comment: How do you run the server? You may have a PYTHONPATH that's missing a path setting, but how to set that properly (or check it), may depend on how you run the server.

Comment: I haven't heard about a `.env` file. Perhaps that's new, but it doesn't sound like it's Django specific. Where did you read about needing/creating a `.env` file in the first place?

Comment: You need .env file to store enviroment variables such as SECRET_KEY and other sensitive informations.

Comment: I run server with simple command. pythong manage.py runserver and everthing is fine. Thats also issue. But when i want to run this file i get this import error

Comment: I don't think the `.env` is a Django thing per se; it's just a convention, and you may have to read it separately. But it has also nothing to do with your error, which just means your settings module can't be found.

Comment: I know mate. Thats issue. I cant figure it out

Comment: What's the dota package you are trying to import? And are you using a virtual environment (see https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)? By the way you should probably rename your `.env` file to `.envfile` to avoid confusion and use a package to load those environment variable (see https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ for example).

Comment: Its not package. dota is app, module and inside dota there is settings.py. In settings.py i have those files that I linked at top. I just want to import SECRET_KEY and all the other stuff into another folder and another file users/send_mail.py. Yes im using virtualenv

Comment: You probably have an issue with loading the other files from various directory then. You will need to check how local packages are loaded in python: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#packages

Comment: Yea correct, i have issue with loading other files. Ill check this now

Comment: I just read this and i dont have that mistake here. I followed this rulnes. Its streightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to access project settings is to import settings object from django.conf module. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

Comment: can i maybe furher explain what i need to do here? I read this but I dont quite understand it

Comment: I need to import individual module. With django.conf i import all the settings